# For loop stop when number is reached

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
car_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="vehicle-item__title"]')
carnamelist = []
for cars in car_names:
    # print(len(cars))
    carnamelist.append(cars.text)
    # print((len(car_names)))
```

car_names are now 50, but I would like to stop when it reaches 17

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to `zip` with a range of 17 (`zip` stops automatically when either input is exhausted):

```
for cars, _ in zip(car_names, range(17)):
    carnamelist.append(cars.text)
```

Another would be to `break` in your loop:

```
for cars in car_names:
    carnamelist.append(cars.text)
    if len(carnamelist) >= 17:
        break
```

My approach would be to use `zip` and make it a list a comprehension:

```
carnamelist = [cars.text for cars, _ in zip(car_names, range(17))]
```

If `car_names` is a list (or anything else that supports slicing) you can do this much more simply with a slice:

```
carnamelist = [cars.text for cars in car_names[:17]]
```

Comment: Ok thx a lot for these tips. I forgot to mention that this number 17 is dynamic. It changes every other scrape run.